# reset inherited opacity/filter:alpha to full transparency

Tags: inheritance, css, transparency, opacity

I have a `<div>` with a black background containing a white `<h1>` element. My `<div>` has an opacity of .4 using the following css combined with IE's method.

```
opacity: .4;
filter:  alpha(opacity=40);
```

This makes my `<div>` and `<h1>` have 40% transparency, but I want the h1 to have full transparency (white). How can I accomplish this with equal browser support? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I would use `background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);` but that's not something IE supports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible - opacity values smaller than 1 can't be overridden by children.

The `h1` would have to be in a different container than the `div`, or you would have to use a transparent PNG with 40% opacity for the background (which again won't work in IE6 without workarounds).

Comment: Excellent, Thank you! I'm going to use the 'in a different container' technique, unless someone else has a better idea.